# How to pass raw <html> to xxx.html using dictionary values in python django

Tags: python, django

After collecting some data in html format I need to display it on base.html using views.py render function. But it shows the raw code instead of showing the proper  view (select dropdown).

I'm using django python on windows pc

`models.py`

```
class query(models.Model):

    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",database="ameya",user="root",password="")
    html = '<table class="table table-bordered datatable responsive" id="table-2"><thead><tr><th>Schedule NO.</th><th>Farmer Name</th><th>University</th><th>District</th><th>Taluk</th><th>Panchayet</th><th>Village</th><th>Crop</th></tr></thead><tbody id="tab_tbody">'

    def __str__(self):     
        htm = '<form action="getFarmer" method="post"><select class="form-control" name="season"><option value="0">-- Select Year --</option><option value="333">All Data</option>'
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        cdt = now.year
        for i in range( 2017,int(cdt) ):
            htm += '<option value="'+str(i)+'">'+str(i)+' - '+str(int(i)+1)+'</option>'
        htm += '</select><input type="submit" value="Search >"></form>'   
        return htm
```

`views.py`

```
def index(request):
    t = query()
    return render(request,"mainapp/base.html",{'html':t})
```

`base.html`

```
<html>
<head><title>AmeyaKrishi Version 2</title></head>
<body>
    <h2>AmeyaKrishi V2 (testing mode): All University Filter</h2><hr>
    <p>{{ html }}</p>   
</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT

[local server output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIAlo.png)

Comment: you can try with `<p>{{ html|safe }}</p> `

Comment: It works!! thank you a lot.. you make my day..

Comment: It would make much more sense for you to render the HTML in the template rather than as a string in the view. Django's templates have for loops. Better still would be to use a Django Form rather than implementing it yourself.

Comment: Yes you are right @AlexHall will do it from now.. thanks